# Constructing a phylogentic tree

Tags: python, tree, bioinformatics, phylogeny

I have a list of list of lists like this

```
matches = [[['rootrank', 'Root'], ['domain', 'Bacteria'], ['phylum', 'Firmicutes'], ['class', 'Clostridia'], ['order', 'Clostridiales'], ['family', 'Lachnospiraceae'], ['genus', 'Lachnospira']], 
           [['rootrank', 'Root'], ['domain', 'Bacteria'], ['phylum', '"Proteobacteria"'], ['class', 'Gammaproteobacteria'], ['order', '"Vibrionales"'], ['family', 'Vibrionaceae'], ['genus', 'Catenococcus']], 
           [['rootrank', 'Root'], ['domain', 'Archaea'], ['phylum', '"Euryarchaeota"'], ['class', '"Methanomicrobia"'], ['order', 'Methanomicrobiales'], ['family', 'Methanomicrobiaceae'], ['genus', 'Methanoplanus']]]
```

And I want to construct a phylogenetic tree from them. I wrote a node class like so (based partially on [this code](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~shipman/xnomo/tree.py)):

```
class Node(object):
    """Generic n-ary tree node object
    Children are additive; no provision for deleting them."""

    def __init__(self, parent, category=None, name=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.category = category
        self.name = name
        self.childList = []

        if  parent is None:
            self.birthOrder  =  0
        else:
            self.birthOrder  =  len(parent.childList)
            parent.childList.append(self)

    def fullPath(self):
        """Returns a list of children from root to self"""
        result  =  []
        parent  =  self.parent
        kid     =  self

        while parent:
            result.insert(0, kid)
            parent, kid  =  parent.parent, parent

        return result

    def ID(self):
        return '{0}|{1}'.format(self.category, self.name)
```

And then I try to construct my tree like this:

```
node = None
for match in matches:
    for branch in match:
        category, name = branch
        node = Node(node, category, name)
        print [n.ID() for n in node.fullPath()]
```

This works for the first match, but when  I start with the second match it is appended at the end of the tree instead of starting again at the top. How would I do that? I tried some variations on searching for the ID, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `node` is always the bottommost node in the tree, and you are always appending to that node.  You need to store the root node.  Since `['rootrank', 'Root']` appears at the beginning of each of the lists, I'd recommend pulling that out and using it as the root.  So you can do something like:

```
rootnode = Node(None, 'rootrank', 'Root')
for match in matches:
    node = rootnode
    for branch in match:
        category, name = branch
        node = Node(node, category, name)
        print [n.ID() for n in node.fullPath()]
```

This will make the `matches` list more readable, and gives the expected output.

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend using a phylogenetics library like [Dendropy](http://pythonhosted.org/DendroPy/).

The 'standard way of writing phylogenetic trees is with the Newick format (parenthetical statements like ((A,B),C)). If you use Dendropy, reading that tree would be as simple as

```
>>> import dendropy
>>> tree1 = dendropy.Tree.get_from_string("((A,B),(C,D))", schema="newick")
```

or to read from a stream

```
>>> tree1 = dendropy.Tree(stream=open("mle.tre"), schema="newick")
```

The creator of the library maintains a nice [tutorial](http://pythonhosted.org/DendroPy/tutorial/index.html) too.

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a favor and don't reinvent the wheel. [Python-graph (a.k.a. pygraph)](https://code.google.com/p/python-graph/) does all that you ask here and most of the things that you'll ask next.